# "Unfortunately, Google play services has stopped." LG Destiny

Tags: google-play-services

Ive tried all of the methods listed by most forums, tech blogs, the google play help group or whatever it is, anyway. There literally has not been a single solution that's worked for others and myself. 
I can't add any google related accounts, anywhere, on anything. 
I've reset about a dozen times. Nothing has proven worth the hours trying to get a solution.

Here are some of the things that I have tried:

- I tried deactivating the device manager, cleared the cache on download manager, Google play store, google play services, reactivated android device manager, and rebooted.
- I have also tried downloading the Google play services apk file from apkmirror.com
- Made sure unknown sources was unchecked,

I use an LG G3 device see screenshot below:

[image]

What do I do and how exactly do I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please would you mind explaining what specific things you did and what failed, so you can get  good answers, otherwise no one would guess what you did and you may end up getting similar answers you previously saw on other forums

Comment: I tried deactivating the device manager, mafe sure unknown sources was unchecked, cleared the cache on download manager, Google play store, google play services, reactivated android device manager, and rebooted.

Comment: Can you also [edit] your question to say what phone you have?

Comment: I've tried downloading other Google play services apks from places like apkmirror. I can't install that's.apk. i just get an unsupported format dialogue. I tried using the downloads app to open them but that didn't work either. I can't acess downloads within this version of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

if nothing works find a stock rom for your phone and flash that (not all phones have the same methods for flashing ,google how to flash stock rom on "your phone".
flashing will format your whole phone!

Comment: I've done all of these steps. I usually rebooted after I did each solution.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any roms or much development at all on xda for my device.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying message that many android users face. The worst thing about this error message is that there is no clarification about why this message appears and how to precisely fix it. I got a great help from **[this](https://geekermag.com/unfortunately-google-play-services-stopped/)** site, to how to resolve this issue. Below are some of the mentioned steps you can try for this.

1. Reboot your device.
2. Clear Google Play Service Cache.
3. Clear Google Service Framework Cache.
4. Uninstall Latest Google Play Service Update.
5. Update Google Play Service.
6. Check Internet Connection.
7. Disconnect and Reconnect Google Account.
   Last and not on the list is Factory Reset.

If the issue is not being solved then you can try Flash Firmware.